# array filter on strings

Tags: php, arrays, array-filter

I have an array of Users and I want to end up with an array where the username or full name contain a certain character (`$char`). My array looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [User] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 36
                    [username] => JohnS
                    [fullname] => John Smith
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [User] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 137
                    [username] => Tim
                    [fullname] => Tim Wilson
                )

        )

)
```

However, when I run this array filter - I end up with an **empty $result array** no matter what value $char is --

```
$result = array_filter($users, 'matches');

function matches($var){
    return stripos($var["User"]["username"].$var["User"]["fullname"], $char) !== false;
}
```

Any ideas??!

Thanks

Comment: Can you `var_export` your array instead of `print_r` ?

Comment: You have to make `$char` global or use closure with `use` construct as a callback for `array_filter`

Comment: array ( 0 => array ( 'User' => array ( 'id' => '36', 'username' => 'JohnS', 'fullname' => 'John Smith' ), ), 1 => array ( 'User' => array ( 'id' => '137', 'username' => 'Tim', 'fullname' => 'Tim Wilson'), ), )

Comment: @Tim Variables defined outside of function aren't accessible inside this function unless you define them as global or in `use` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$char` in your `matches` function is undefined. (If it is a global variable, then you have to add `global $char;` first.)

Or do like below:

```
$result = array_filter($users, function ($var) use ($char) {
  return stripos($var["User"]["username"].$var["User"]["fullname"], $char) !== false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I've not come across this before. Even when setting $q directly before this function in the same file, or including $q in the function variables this didn't work, so this `use` function is great.

Comment: @Tim `use` isn't a function, it is a language construct